# Getting the 'Content' Redirected URL from the Original URL in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, redirect, http-equiv

Looking to get final redirect on case **redirect is on content**.

```
<body>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=../en/" />
</head>
</body>
```